# How to create a custom type declaration(type hinting) in PHP

Tags: php, class, laravel, model-view-controller, yii

I have seen this in few MVC frameworks

```
Class Hotel{

function add(AddRequest $post){
$this->save($post->all());
}

}
```

I would like to create my own type hinting using php class as bellow and
i know there are two ways to do it.

with class:

```
public function myFunction(SomeClass $instance)
```

with interface:

```
public function myfunction(SomeInterface $instance)
```

I Couldn't find any good article about it.Can anyone explain it briefly on how to create our own type hinting and advantages by doing so.

Comment: your suggestion doesn't make you nor me smarter..I dint came here before googling.If you know any you can suggest else ignore it.Don't judge me because of my reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

The first benefit of using type hinting is the validation and self-documentation that comes with it i.e. if you come back to your code that you haven't seen in a while or you working on someone else's code you will be able to see straight away that it must be passed an instance of something specific. The second being, if you do not pass a required instance it will throw an error. (This is all without any extra code)

Furthermore, the use of interfaces allows for different implementations of a class to be passed through but you code will allow it because your interface should declare what the required methods will be (Think different db drivers).

I've not used Yii before so I don't know anything about it. Laravel, on the other hand, works by using `Reflection` and actually injects an instance of the class you require. This is called `Dependency Injection`.

The link below is to a video which will explain the concept in much more detail: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/16

Hope this helps!

Comment: So the term is dependency injection,thanks for that.)

Comment: well little  about yii , its a MVC framework, just similar to laravel but the the use of dependency injection being implemented in background and you wont be noticing it unless dumping the instances once it has been generated.Shrinking it short,they just dont emphasizing on it.